# Get only the drive letter from a path in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to make a script in PowerShell to help easily translate a path like this:

```
H:\MyDoc.docx
```

Into its true absolute path, like this:

```
\\FileServer\UserShares\Organization\Department\Me\MyDoc.docx
```

In this case, I've created a network drive mapping on my local computer that points `H:\` to `\\FileServer\UserShares\Organization\Department\Me\`, but I need to easily expand the mapped path in order to share it with other users who may not have the drive mapping.

Getting the path for the drive is easy.

```
(Get-PSDrive H).DisplayRoot
```

However, I encounter a problem when I try write a more generic script that can automatically adapt to paths which might point to other mapped drives (I do have several). What I'm having a hard time figuring out is how to extract just the drive letter from a given path.

I thought `Split-Path` would help, but it appears to only be able to pull the path apart in chunks - the "Parent" and the "Leaf" - neither of which will give only the drive letter.

Is there a way to get *just* the drive letter from a given path in PowerShell?

Note: I need this to work for paths that point to files *or* folders.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the `PSDrive` property of the FileInfo object:

```
(Get-Item .\your\path\to\file.ext).PSDrive.Name
```

Comment: Ah, so instead of treating the string itself as the path I use the string to get the actual object via `Get-ChildItem` and then work with the data from that object. I can see this working for files, but what about folders?

Comment: Precisely. Will work for folders too, they still exist on a drive.

Comment: Actually not, since `Get-ChildItem` returns all objects within the folder instead of the folder itself. Replace it with `Get-Item` and it will work for files *and* folders, though.

Comment: Added benefit of this method: Works for relative paths too!

Comment: Ah, a remaining bit of the script now - since I still technically don't have a way to "break off" the drive from the path - is to get *just* the non-drive portions of the target path so that I can append it to the end of the share path. That would be a separate question though, I guess.

Comment: Use a neater version of: `$f = get-item yourfile.txt; $f.fullname.trimstart((get-item $f).psdrive.name + ":")` or `$f.fullname -ireplace "[a-z]:(.*)", '$1'`

Comment: The first one is better, I think. Or at least a better start. It remains adaptable to drive paths that are more than one letter long - should there ever come a use case for it.

Comment: Think I'll try something like: `$p=Read-Host; $d=(GI $p).PSDrive.Name; $t=(GI $p).FullName.TrimStart($x+':'); $n=(GDR $d).DisplayPath; ECHO "$n$t";`

Answer (score 19):

As of PowerShell 3.0, Split-Path now offers the `-Qualifier` option:

```
-Qualifier
   Indicates that this cmdlet returns only the qualifier of the specified path.
   For the FileSystem or registry providers, the qualifier is the drive of the
   provider path, such as C: or HKCU:.
```

Using OP's example:

```
PS C:\> Split-Path -Path "H:\MyDoc.docx" -Qualifier
```

returns `H:`

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution that works for most cases, but it's a bit "hacky" in the sense that it's just returning part of a string instead of a specific component of a file path.

---

Assuming the drive is represented by a single letter (as most, if not all, network mappings are), you can get around the issue by handling the path as a string instead of trying to treat it as a multi-part "path" object. This makes the issue very simple, since the drive letter will always be the first character in the string and PowerShell handles strings as arrays of individual characters.

For example, if the script stores the provided path in `$MyPath`, the way you'd get the drive letter is just:

```
$DriveLetter = $MyPath[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
((Get-Location).Path.Split(":")).Get(0)

Returns just the provider.  Output:

PS SQLSERVER:\> ((Get-Location).Path.Split(":")).Get(0)

SQLSERVER

PS F:\Backups> ((Get-Location).Path.Split(":")).Get(0)

F

etc...
```